# How to copy a cropped image onto the original one, given the coordinates of the center of the crop

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm cropping an image like this:

```
self.rst = self.img_color[self.param_a_y:self.param_b_y,
                        self.param_a_x:self.param_b_x:, ]
```

How do I copy this image back to the original one. The data I have available are the coordinates of the original image, which makes the center  of the crop.

Seems like there's no`copy_to()` function for python

Comment: `self.rst` already refers to a view of the original image -- unless you assign a new image to the variable, changing any pixels will change pixels in the original large image. To write back into the same area, just swap the sides: `self.img_color[self.param_a_y:self.param_b_y,
                        self.param_a_x:self.param_b_x:,:] = img`

Comment: @DanMašek, I didn't think this one through. Thanks!

Comment: @DanMašek, doing that makes the ROI in the original picture darker than the rest of the image, so I assume there is an addition happening? That is not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed myself getting copy_to() working a few days ago, but came up with a difeerent solution: You can uses masks for this task.

I have an example at hand which shows how to create a mask from a defined colour range using inrange. With that mask, you create two partial images (=masks), one for the old content and one for the new content, the not used area in both images is back. Finally, a simple bitwise_or combines both images.

This works for arbitrary shapes, so you can easily adapt this to rectangular ROIs.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('image.png')

rows,cols,bands = img.shape 
print rows,cols,bands

# Create image with new colour for replacement
new_colour_image= np.zeros((rows,cols,3), np.uint8)
new_colour_image[:,:]= (255,0,0) 

# Define range of color to be exchanged (in this case only one single color, but could be range of colours)
lower_limit = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_limit = np.array([0,0,0])

# Generate mask for the pixels to be exchanged
new_colour_mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_limit, upper_limit)

# Generate mask for the pixels to be kept
old_image_mask=cv2.bitwise_not(new_colour_mask)

# Part of the image which is kept
img2= cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, old_image_mask)

# Part of the image which is replaced
new_colour_image=cv2.bitwise_and(new_colour_image,new_colour_image, new_colour_mask)

#Combination of the two parts
result=cv2.bitwise_or(img2, new_colour_image)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.imshow('mask',new_colour_mask)
cv2.imshow('r',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```